# Checking if a variable is included in a list of words in SCSS

Tags: css, sass

In a SCSS mixin definition, I want to check if an argument is one of predefined strings. In the following example, how can I make a condition to check whether `$arg` is `"foo"`, `"bar"`, or `"baz"`? If not, I want to raise an error.

```
@mixin my-mixin($arg){
  @if some-condition {
    @error "argument must be `foo`, `bar`, or `baz`."
  };
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So far there is no built-in method to achieve that. However you could simply write your own [`@function`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#function_directives) (for instance called `in_list`<sup>1</sup>) which uses [`index()`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#index-instance_method) method in order to check the existence of a [value](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#variables_) in a [list](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#lists) as follows:

```
/**
 * in_list — Checks if a value exists in a list
 *
 * @param  $value the needle
 * @param  $list  the haystack
 * @return boolen TRUE if $value is found in the $list, FALSE otherwise.   
 */
@function in_list($value, $list) {
    @return (false != index($list, $value));
}
```

For instance:

```
$list: foo, bar, baz;
$val: qux;

 ...
@if in_list($val, $list) {
    // do something
} @else {
    @error "$val argument must exist in #{$list}; was '#{$val}'";
}
```

---

<sup>1. The function name and the syntax is inspired of PHP [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function.</sup>

Comment: Actually, `index()` itself would work in my situation. Thanks for letting me know about it.

Comment: @sawa You're welcome, just note that `index()` returns the numeric position of a value rather than a boolean true/false.

Answer (score 1):

The official example uses:

```
@if list.index($list, $value) { }
```

and

```
@if not list.index($list, $value) { }
```

https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/lists